# Create smart contract with flutter and web3dart

Tags: flutter, dart, ethereum, solidity, web3dart

I am currently trying to create a smart contract with flutter and web3dart. I am able to read a created smart contract with the abi. but I can't find a way, to create a new one.

reading was pretty simple:

```
var ticketABI = ContractABI.parseFromJSON(_TICKET_ABI_EXTRACT, "Ticket");

var ticketContract = new DeployedContract(ticketABI, new EthereumAddress(_TICKET_ADDRESS), ethClient, credentials);
    
var getTicketCreator = ticketContract.findFunctionsByName("getTicketInformation").first;
    
var ticketResponse = await new Transaction(keys: credentials, maximumGas: 0)
          .prepareForCall(ticketContract, getTicketCreator, [])
          .call(ethClient);
    
var ticket = new Ticket.fromResponse(ticketResponse);
```

But I cannot figure out how to create a new smart contract. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

web3dart doesn't support the creation of a new smart contract at the moment.